# How do I Provision a Transport Handler for IoTHub?

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-central, azure-iot-hub-device-management, azure-data-factory

I am trying to connect to IoTHub to provision my device.

I am in a Blazor WASM app.

I have created the Security Provider Symmetric Key via:

```
SecurityProvider symmetricKeyProvider = new SecurityProviderSymmetricKey(parameters.DeviceId, parameters.DeviceSymmetricKey, null);
```

However my next line I call:

```
            ProvisioningTransportHandler mqttTransportHandler = new ProvisioningTransportHandlerMqtt(TransportFallbackType.TcpOnly);
```

I have tried it with both the TcpOnly fallback along with not passing in any fallback and both give me the same error.  The exception is:

```
Error provisioning device: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Provisioning.Client.Transport.ProvisioningTransportHandlerMqtt' threw an exception.
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Provisioning.Client.Transport.ProvisioningTransportHandlerMqtt' threw an exception.
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: failed to create a child event loop.
 ---> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
   at System.Threading.Thread.Start()
   at DotNetty.Common.Concurrency.SingleThreadEventExecutor..ctor(IEventExecutorGroup parent, String threadName, TimeSpan breakoutInterval, IQueue`1 taskQueue)
   at DotNetty.Common.Concurrency.SingleThreadEventExecutor..ctor(IEventExecutorGroup parent, String threadName, TimeSpan breakoutInterval)
   at DotNetty.Transport.Channels.SingleThreadEventLoop..ctor(IEventLoopGroup parent, String threadName, TimeSpan breakoutInterval)
   at DotNetty.Transport.Channels.SingleThreadEventLoop..ctor(IEventLoopGroup parent)
   at DotNetty.Transport.Channels.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<>c.<.cctor>b__24_0(IEventLoopGroup group)
   at DotNetty.Transport.Channels.MultithreadEventLoopGroup..ctor(Func`2 eventLoopFactory, Int32 eventLoopCount)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at DotNetty.Transport.Channels.MultithreadEventLoopGroup..ctor(Func`2 eventLoopFactory, Int32 eventLoopCount)
   at DotNetty.Transport.Channels.MultithreadEventLoopGroup..ctor()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Provisioning.Client.Transport.ProvisioningTransportHandlerMqtt..cctor()
```

Comment: What target framework are you building against?  The System.PlatformNotSupportedException is mostly related to wrong target or packages required for that target.

Comment: @humblejay AspNetCore 6.0.5